# PrintDocument coming up blank

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdocument

I have this method that should generate what I need to print:

```
    private void myPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(makeBarcode(), 500, 1000);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Do Not Seperate", makeFont(), Brushes.Black, 100, 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Choking Hazard", makeFont(), Brushes.Black, 200, 2);
    }
```

How ever when I print it, it comes up blanks and when I look at it in PrintPreviewDialog it comes up blanket. What I am missing here?

This is my constructor by the way:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myPrintDocument.PrintPage += new
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler
            (this.myPrintDocument_PrintPage);
    }
```

For Mark

```
    private Image makeBarcode()
    {
        InventoryBLL ibll = new InventoryBLL();
        Barcode b = new Barcode();
        b.IncludeLabel = true;
        b.Height = 35;
        b.Width = 200;
        b.BackColor = Color.White;
        b.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        b.Alignment = BarcodeLib.AlignmentPositions.CENTER;
        return b.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, ibll.getFNSKU(txtASIN.Text));

    }
    private Font makeFont()
    {
        Font myFont = new Font("arial", 10);
        return myFont;
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your makeFont and your makebarcode methods.

Comment: Did you look into `e.MarginBounds()` and make sure you are drawing inside the page?

Comment: @MarkHall I added those two methods.

Comment: Have you tried calling `e.Graphics.Flush()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
   ...
   e.Graphics.DrawString("Choking Hazard", ..., 200, 2);
```

That string is going to print at 200 inches.  Somewhat safe to assume that your paper isn't that big, 8 inch is about typical.  You cannot see what's off the paper.  Consider changing the PageUnit or using much smaller floating point print positions.